# Slow query in postgresql geonames db despite indexes

Tags: postgresql, geonames

I imported all tables from http://www.geonames.org/ into my local postgresql 9.5.3.0 database and peppered it with indexes like so:

```
create extension pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX name_trgm_idx ON geoname USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX fcode_trgm_idx ON geoname USING GIN (fcode gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX fclass_trgm_idx ON geoname USING GIN (fclass gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX alternatename_trgm_idx ON alternatename USING GIN (alternatename gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX isolanguage_trgm_idx ON alternatename USING GIN (isolanguage gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX alt_geoname_id_idx ON alternatename (geonameid)
```

And now I would like to query the country names in different languages and cross reference the geonames attributes with these alternative names like so:

```
select g.geonameid as geonameid ,a.alternatename as name,g.country as country, g.fcode as fcode
from geoname g,alternatename a
where
      a.isolanguage=LOWER('de')
      and a.alternatename ilike '%Sa%'
      and (a.ishistoric = FALSE OR a.ishistoric IS NULL)
      and (a.isshortname = TRUE OR a.isshortname IS NULL)
      and a.geonameid = g.geonameid
      and g.fclass='A'
      and g.fcode ='PCLI';
```

Unfortunately though this query takes as long as 13 to 15 seconds on an octacore machine with a fast SSD. 'Explain analyze verbose' shows this:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..237138.04 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=1408.443..10878.115 rows=15 loops=1)
  Output: g.geonameid, a.alternatename, g.country, g.fcode
  ->  Seq Scan on public.alternatename a  (cost=0.00..233077.17 rows=481 width=18) (actual time=0.750..10862.089 rows=2179 loops=1)
        Output: a.alternatenameid, a.geonameid, a.isolanguage, a.alternatename, a.ispreferredname, a.isshortname, a.iscolloquial, a.ishistoric
        Filter: (((a.alternatename)::text ~~* '%Sa%'::text) AND ((a.isolanguage)::text = 'de'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 10675099
  ->  Index Scan using pk_geonameid on public.geoname g  (cost=0.43..8.43 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=2179)
        Output: g.geonameid, g.name, g.asciiname, g.alternatenames, g.latitude, g.longitude, g.fclass, g.fcode, g.country, g.cc2, g.admin1, g.admin2, g.admin3, g.admin4, g.population, g.elevation, g.gtopo30, g.timezone, g.moddate
        Index Cond: (g.geonameid = a.geonameid)
        Filter: ((g.fclass = 'A'::bpchar) AND ((g.fcode)::text = 'PCLI'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
```

Which to me seems to indicate that somehow a sequence scan is performed on 481 rows (which I deem to be fairly low), but nevertheless takes very long. I currently can't make sense of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Postgres underestimates the number of rows for `alternatename`. And apparently the index on `alternatename.alternatename` is not used. Did you run `analyze alternatename` to update statistics? How many rows do the conditions on `ishistoric` and `isshortname` remove from the table? Maybe if you creating a combined index on those might help or just the one that removes more rows from the result. It would probably help if you can get rid of the NULL values in the boolean columns so that you don't need `or is null` (which is hard to index properly)

Comment: Unrelated to the performance: you should really stop using the old, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause and use an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: I did analyze alternatename with no results. If I remove ishistoric and isshortname from the equation it gives me a 2 second boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigrams only work if you have minimum of 3 characters you're searching for `%Sa%` won't work, `%foo%` will. However your indexes are still not good enough. Depending on what parameters are dynamic use multicolumn or filtered indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX jkb1 ON geoname(fclass, fcode, geonameid, country);
CREATE INDEX jkb2 ON geoname(geonameid, country) WHERE fclass = 'A' AND fcode = 'PCLI';
```

Same for the other table:

```
CREATE INDEX jkb3 ON alternatename(geonameid, alternatename) WHERE (a.ishistoric = FALSE OR a.ishistoric IS NULL)
      AND (a.isshortname = TRUE OR a.isshortname IS NULL) AND isolanguage=LOWER('de')
```

Comment: Of course you are right. select times drop to below 25ms using parameterized indexes and to 120ms without parameters. Thank you so much.